truncate url in address bar using urlwriterfilter
I have a question about the urlrewritefilter and until now I could not find anything about it in the net. I have to truncate url in address bar using urlwriterfilter, the goal is to have a shorten and constant url in address bar.
for example:https://www.domaine.com/s/ or https://www.domaine.com/s/v or https://www.domaine.com/s/v/?GET..... it will always on address bar https://www.domaine.com
I have tried with some parameters in urlrewrite.xml but without results.
I expect to show me a clue using rule in urlrewrite.xml

You can't achieve this with server-side URL rewriting. If you have two different pieces of content that you want to be able to request from your server, then you need two different URLs for that. It can be done on the client side, either by wrapping the whole page into a frameset, or by manipulating the URL after it has loaded (HTML5 History API.) But it really makes little sense to begin with, for most use cases. Users would not be able to simply reload the current page they were on, and they won't be able to properly bookmark an individual page or share it on social media, either.

Thank you for your prompt reply.
I think I've misspoken on the subject, in fact I just want to fix the address in the address bar (for security reasons), we don't need the user to copy or create a shortcut.
All this using urlwriterfilter of course.
Thanks again.
